# How to run all the cmdlets that “Get-Command” returns?

Tags: powershell

I will like to run all the cmdlets that “Get-Command” returns.

The Idea will be to run something like:

```
Get-Command Get-*Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "Get-Service*"}
```

And for each cmdlet that is return. Append something (e.g. the service name) and run it. 
So far this is what I have:

```
function Do-InvokeCommand {
param( $CmdletName )

Write-Host "Will Invoke-Command: $CmdletName"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$CmdletName 'notepad'} 
}

$Cmdlet_List = Get-Command Get-*Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "Get-Service*"} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}|Out-String

Foreach ($Cmdlet in $Cmdlet_List){Do-InvokeCommand -CmdletName $Cmdlet}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? i don't see any point in what you are showing ... [*blush*]

Comment: FWIW, I've used convention-based naming of cmdlets and done things like "get-command \*HealthMonitor\*" and then run them (not exactly this, but similar)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work (using the invoke operator &):

```
get-command get-service,get-process | foreach-object {& $_}
```

Comment: Thank you.
That gets the command running.
and to add the name of the service I just add it after the $_:

get-command get-service  | foreach-object {& $_ natepad}